Ruby (3.3.4) and Rails (7.1) - rails s Zeitwerk - uninitialized constant Utils::ScriptsUtils::Utils (NameError)
I am trying to update my ruby app from ruby 2.6.6 to ruby 3.3.4 and Rail 5.1 to Rails 7.1
I know it is not a good practice to do so, but in my case (which is a bit complicated) I felt I didn't have much choice
I manage to generate correctly the Gemfile.lock, and I had some LoadError problems when using rails s command
I replaced a lot require with require_relative (which worked previously, but not anymore, i don't really know why), but now I have a new error, and I don't what to do, since it seems to be directly in zeotwerk file
here is the log :
$ rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 7.1.3.4 application starting in development
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
Exiting
C:/Users/abris/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.16/lib/zeitwerk/cref.rb:91:in `const_get': uninitialized constant Utils::ScriptsUtils::Utils (NameError)

    @mod.const_get(@cname, false)
        ^^^^^^^^^^
        from C:/Users/abris/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.16/lib/zeitwerk/cref.rb:91:in `get'
        from C:/Users/abris/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.16/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:173:in `block in actual_eager_load_dir'
        from C:/Users/abris/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.16/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:47:in `block in ls'
        from C:/Users/abris/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.16/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:25:in `each'
        from C:/Users/abris/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.16/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:25:in `ls'
        from C:/Users/abris/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.16/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:168:in `actual_eager_load_dir'
        from C:/Users/abris/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.16/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load'
        from C:/Users/abris/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.16/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:16:in `each'
        from C:/Users/abris/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.16/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:16:in `block in eager_load'
        from C:/Users/abris/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.16/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:10:in `synchronize'
        from C:/Users/abris/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.16/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:10:in `eager_load'
        from C:/Users/abris/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.16/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:413:in `block in eager_load_all'
        from C:/Users/abris/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.16/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:411:in `each'
        from C:/Users/abris/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.16/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:411:in `eager_load_all'
        from C:/Users/abris/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:80:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from C:/Users/abris/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/Users/abris/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
        from C:/Users/abris/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/tsort.rb:231:in `block in tsort_each'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/tsort.rb:353:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/tsort.rb:434:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/tsort.rb:352:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/tsort.rb:229:in `tsort_each'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/tsort.rb:208:in `tsort_each'
        from C:/Users/abris/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/Users/abris/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.4/lib/rails/application.rb:426:in `initialize!'
        from D:/Programmation/mta-baptiste/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
        from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from C:/Users/abris/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/rack-2.2.9/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
        from C:/Users/abris/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/rack-2.2.9/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
        from C:/Users/abris/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/rack-2.2.9/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
        from C:/Users/abris/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/rack-2.2.9/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
        from C:/Users/abris/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/rack-2.2.9/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        from C:/Users/abris/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/rack-2.2.9/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
        from C:/Users/abris/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/rack-2.2.9/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
        from C:/Users/abris/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:76:in `log_to_stdout'
        from C:/Users/abris/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:36:in `start'
        from C:/Users/abris/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:145:in `block in perform'
        from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
        from C:/Users/abris/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:136:in `perform'
        from C:/Users/abris/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/thor-1.3.1/lib/thor/command.rb:28:in `run'
        from C:/Users/abris/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/thor-1.3.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/Users/abris/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:178:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/Users/abris/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/thor-1.3.1/lib/thor.rb:527:in `dispatch'
        from C:/Users/abris/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:73:in `perform'
        from C:/Users/abris/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.4/lib/rails/command.rb:71:in `block in invoke'
        from C:/Users/abris/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.4/lib/rails/command.rb:149:in `with_argv'
        from C:/Users/abris/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.4/lib/rails/command.rb:69:in `invoke'
        from C:/Users/abris/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in replace_require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

The line in D:/Programmation/mta-baptiste/config/environment.rb:5 is the following : Rails.application.initialize!
And here are my eager_load_paths in application.rb :
config.eager_load = true
    config.eager_load_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib/assets"
    config.eager_load_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib/tasks"
    config.eager_load_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib/utilities"
    config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join("lib")

    config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')

I have not much experienced with this kind of stuff, so I am new to this kind of errors, and I don't really know what to do
Does anyone has an idea ?
OS: Windows 10
Ruby version (ruby -v) : ruby 3.3.4 (2024-07-09 revision be1089c8ec) [x64-mingw-ucrt]
Rails version (rails -v): Rails 7.1.3.4
Thanks

There is a reason that it's not good practice to make such a large version migration! Why would you ignore standard practice and expect that there will not be problems. Make small steps, and your problems stand a chance of being easier to debug. Otherwise this is likely just the first of many difficult problems.

if you're requiring your files from lib, then you don't need to autoload or eager load lib. and if you want to autoload, then you need to follow the correct file structure, for example, lib/utils/scripts_utils/utils.rb has to define Utils::ScriptsUtils::Utils otherwise you'll get that error. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html

@Alex Thanks,this utils.rb is not in /lib,but somwhere else(it was like that when i got the project), but I suppose it is the same answer,I need to define module Utils::ScriptsUtils::Utils  ?
@LesNightingill I didn't expect to have 0 problems, but I supposed in my conditions it would have been faster, like I said i'm not very experienced
Do you both think it would be faster if I undo my change and start updating more "slowly" between each version ?If so how do I know which version I am allowed to jump to ? Do I need to uninstall older version each time or just changing the path will do ?

@Alex just reminded, the file utils.rb (for example) does not have a module defined in it, I don't know if that change something about zeitwerk

you require your files, that means you don't need to autoload anything. if you have lib in autoload paths then you have to follow a proper file structure and stop requiring files manually. rails 7 upgrade is hard. i don't think upgrading to rails 6 will prepare you for rails 7 upgrade. normally you upgrade every minor version 6.0 > 6.1 > 7.0 > 7.1 https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html . you can run bin/rails zeitwerk:check to verify that you app can be eager loaded properly.

@Alex Thanks for your answers, I will see what I can do
